# Inheritance in delphi

Tags: delphi, inheritance, overriding

I have three classes like:
ClassA,ClassB,ClassC.
ClasssB inherited from ClassA, and ClassC inherited from ClassB,
there is a method in classA and overrided in ClassB and ClassC.
and I want to refer to method in ClassA instead of ClassB when it is run in ClassC using "inherited", 
how can I do this?

best regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me, I found it.